# How to display all WordPress user without admin list with user info

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-wordpress

I want to display all my users info in my index.php 
ie : User Name / Full Name / Social Links / Profile Picture etc etc.

Can any one tell me please how to display all wordpress users list in index.php without admin?

**Code**:

```
<?php
$blogusers = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=subscriber' );
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) { ?>
<?php
echo 'Username: ' . $user->user_login . '';
echo 'User email: ' . $user->user_email . '';
echo 'User first name: ' . $user->user_firstname . '';
echo 'User last name: ' . $user->user_lastname . '';
echo 'User display name: ' . $user->display_name . '';
?>
<?php } ?> .
```

I want user output in html div css styling. How to do that? Is there any other option?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: `<?php
$blogusers = get_users( 'blog_id=1&orderby=nicename&role=subscriber' );
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) { ?>
<?php
    echo 'Username: ' . $user->user_login . '';
    echo 'User email: ' . $user->user_email . '';
    echo 'User first name: ' . $user->user_firstname . '';
    echo 'User last name: ' . $user->user_lastname . '';
    echo 'User display name: ' . $user->display_name . '';
    echo 'User url: ' . $user->user_url . '<br />'; ?>
    
<?php } ?> `

i want user output in html div css styling.. how to do that ? is there any other option?

Comment: Kindly edit your question and place your tried code in same.

Comment: :( i am beginner on stackoverflow...

Comment: updated code in qus. part please check...

Answer (score 2):

> If you want to exclude only *administrator* from user list then you
>   have to pass `role__not_in` argument from `get_users`.

```
$args = [
    'blog_id' => 1,
    'role__not_in' => ['administrator'],
    'orderby' => 'nicename',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'fields' => 'all',
];
$users = get_users($args);

print_r($users);
```

Hope this helps!